# RSS Feed creator - cannot see any content in my website?

Tags: html, wordpress, rss

http://juniorgoldreport.com/ - is the website I'm trying to create an RSS feed for and SEO better.

https://feedity.com/ - is what I'm using to see if I can create the feed, and then ultimately create an app.

A decent amount of my front page content is built via plugin that organize my post's making the maintenance of the website much easier for me, and allowing my employer to post content with ease as well.

Taking a look at the feed, it seems that the website cannot see anything.

From my understanding these post's are being displayed via a proper HTML format, the have `h1` tags and proper `div` blocks and `classes`.

Do you guys have any suggestions as to how I should I could go about creating a proper feed? Is this a common issue within wordpress?

I'm currently building another website from scratch with a custom CMS (not via wordpress)

What are you suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS feeds are built into Wordpress. Take a look at [this page from the Codex about feeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds) and how to access them.

As a primer you use http://juniorgoldreport.com/feed/ and get the RSS. If you want to access a specific category you'd use http://juniorgoldreport.com/category/[categoryslug]/feed. You can do the same thing with tags.

As for a non Wordpress site I can't say what the best way would be. There are many options.